# Embedded Profile Mismatch dialog box in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-profile

Is there a best option to choose when the mismatched color profile dialog box opens when opening a document into Illustrator or Photoshop for that matter.

It reads "The document has an embedded color profile that does not match the current RGB working space."

The options are: use the embedded - convert to working space - discard embedded (don't color manage)

I have the CC version of illustrator if that matters.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD.SE. This is not a discussion forum so you would be much better of asking what the difference between the three are than to ask what is the best option. You can edit the wording with the edit button. Best is not defined, therefore the answer depends. Although you almost certainly mostly never want to use option number 3.

Comment: Welcome! I second what joojaa says. Please try and edit your question into, well, a question :). If you have any... questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is not clearly defined, it depends on context so there's no way i can answer what best is.

In general you want to color manage, not doing so does you no favors. So unless you know what color management is, extremely well. Do not choose option *discard embedded (don't color manage)*. It is reserved for very special situations.

Choosing between the two other options is a bit more tricky. In general i tend to favor keeping the original profile, if there is no obstacle why not doing so, as this does possibly destroy and change the data permanently. There are several reasons to convert tough.

1. You are going to merge data from multiple sources and wish to convert to one of the profiles.
2. You need to interact with unmanaged sources that play well in another space. Either because you have managed it that way or your familiar with results in that space better.
3. Your end result will be converted to sRGB anyway. This is a bit dubious but might help if you copy paste screen captures for example.
4. you nee dto do CMYK to RGB or vice versa..